# Equivalent of "case" for np.where

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, where-clause

np.where lets you pick values to assign for a boolean type query, e.g.

```
test = [0,1,2]
np.where(test==0,'True','False')
print test
['True','False','False']
```

Which is basically an 'if' statement. Is there a pythonic way of having an 'if, else if, else' kind of statement (with different cases) for a numpy array?

This is my workaround:

```
color = [0,1,2]
color = np.where(color==0,'red',color)
color = np.where(color==1,'blue',color)
color = np.where(color==2,'green',color)
print color
['red','blue','green']
```

But I wonder if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 11):

[numpy.select()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is what you want here. It is the numpy version of case when. Syntax:

```
import numpy as np
color = np.array([0,1,2])
condlist = [color == 1, color == 2, color == 3]
choicelist = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='unknown')
```

returns:

```
array(['unknown', 'red', 'blue'], dtype='<U7')
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.choose` is something of a multielement `where`:

```
In [97]: np.choose([0,1,1,2,0,1],['red','green','blue'])
Out[97]: 
array(['red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green'], 
      dtype='<U5')
In [113]: np.choose([0,1,2],[0,np.array([1,2,3])[:,None], np.arange(10,13)])
Out[113]: 
array([[ 0,  1, 12],
       [ 0,  2, 12],
       [ 0,  3, 12]])
```

In the more complex cases it helps to have a good handle on broadcasting.

There are limits, for example no more than 32 choices.  It's not used nearly as much as `np.where`.

And sometimes you just want to apply `where` or boolean masking multiple times:

```
In [115]: x
Out[115]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [116]: x[x<4] += 10
In [117]: x
Out[117]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [118]: x[x>8] -=3
In [119]: x
Out[119]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  6,  7,  8]])
In [120]: x[(4<x)&(x<8)] *=2
In [121]: x
Out[121]: 
array([[14,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 4, 10, 12, 14],
       [ 8, 12, 14,  8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the more Pythonic ways to do this would be to use a list comprehension, like this:

```
>>> color = [0,1,2]
>>> ['red' if c == 0 else 'blue' if c == 1 else 'green' for c in color]
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

It's fairly intuitive if you read it. For a given item in the list `color`, the value in the new list will be `'red'` if the color is `0`, `'blue'` if it's `1`, and `'green'` otherwise. I don't know if I would take the `if` `else`s in a list comprehension further than three, though. A `for` loop would be appropriate there.

Or you could use a dictionary, which might be more "Pythonic," and would be much more scalable:

```
>>> color_dict = {0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green'}
>>> [color_dict[number] for number in color]
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```